# Daily Avg in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple sql below. I want to calculate the daily average. But I will have to change the parameters and the number of days every day when I run my sql. What is a better way to eliminate these repeated steps?

```
Declare start_dt as datetime
Declare end-dt as datetime 

Set start_dt ='10/01/16'
Set end_dt = '10/31/16

Select
Product_Name,
Count(Qty) /30 --want to calculate the average last 30 days
From temp 
Where delivery_dt >=start_dt
And delivery_dt<end_dt
Group by product_name
```

As noticed above, I have to manually change the parameters for the date range and the numbers of days to get my average. Is there a way in sql server that I don't have to change the parameters and numbers of my average? And I would like my average results shown as `float`.

Comment: What flavor of RDBMS you have? Hover over the sql-tag, it'll make clear why I ask that question.

Comment: Final paragraph says sql server.

Comment: Google either getdate() or dateadd.

Comment: I use sql server 2012

Comment: Just change `30` to `DATEDIFF(dd,start_dt,end-dt)` and it will work dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you.

```
DECLARE @Start_dt DATETIME
DECLARE @End_dt   DATETIME

SET @Start_dt = GETDATE()
SET @End_dt = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @Start_dt);


SELECT  Product_Name,
        Count(Qty)/DATEDIFF(DAY,@Start_dt,@End_dt) AS [Daily Average] --want to calculate the average last 30 days
FROM temp 
WHERE (delivery_dt >= @Start_dt) AND (delivery_dt < @End_dt)
GROUP BY Product_Name
```

However, you've mentioned that you often use this kind of sql query so I would recommend that you create stored procedure for this one and just call it a day.
For creating procedures you can take a look at microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a stored procedure with parameter endDate and dateDifference,
for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Get_Average_Quantiity(@EndDate DateTime, @DateDifference int)
AS
Declare @StartDate DateTime = DATEADD(Day, @DateDifference, @EndDate)
Select
Product_Name,
CAST(COUNT(Qty) AS FLOAT) / @DateDifference -
From temp 
Where delivery_dt >=@StartDate 
And delivery_dt<@EndDate
Group by product_name
```

To return float I use:

```
CAST(COUNT(Qty) AS FLOAT) / @DateDifference
```

@DateDifference will probably be 30 in your case, but you can change it according to your specific scenario without changing the procedure. Same is with endDate.

Comment: This has nothing to do with an aggregation over a time frame. Your logic assumes 1 row for every day.

Comment: example you have 164 days. average result for time period without cast would be 5, with cast 5.28. Does not change code logic in any way, only the result.

Comment: @aNerd, I don't have acess to create a procedure. Is there a way to go around it? Thanks

Comment: @joe Well, this is probably because they do not want you to make DML queries. Sorry, i don't know a way around. You will probably have to execute the same query with the new parameters every day.